# Completely uninstalling Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: windows, wubi

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 with Wubi. Then after testing it, I decided to uninstall it. I went to control panel and uninstalled Ubuntu. When I restarted my computer is still had the dual boot option to go to either Windows 7 or Ubuntu. When I selected Ubuntu, it said it couldn't run Windows and to put the repair diak. How can i completely uninstall Ubuntu form my computer?

Comment: You could just wipe that partition. As good as uninstalling.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu partition, since he used Wubi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are seeing is a leftover in the Windows boot loader.

Quote from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide/#Uninstallation on how to remove it:

```
In Windows XP you need to edit C:\boot.ini and delete the Ubuntu/Wubi
line. Alternatively you can modify the boot menu via Control
Panel > System > Advanced > Startup and Recovery and pressing "Edit".

For Windows 98 you have to edit C:\config.sys and remove the Wubi block.

For Windows Vista/7, you can use the built-in bcdedit command or install
EasyBCD to edit the boot menu. To use bcdedit, run cmd.exe as an
administrator, then enter bcdedit to show all boot entries, note the {GUID}
specified for the Ubuntu entry, and then remove it: bcdedit /delete {GUID}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. With the EasyBCD I was able to remove it from the boot option. I could also now change my other boot option, too.